# error installing ubuntu 20.04 in msi p65 creator 8rd with bug #1871268

Tags: software-installation, 20.04

i was installing ubuntu 20.04.1 in my pc, al was going well, i chose normal installation, the progression bar was almost full, and after 15 secs installing packages, it showed an error and opened me this page https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/glibc/+bug/1871268 . im still at this point, could someone help me quickly?

Comment: Does your hardware have an NVIDIA card? Did you select to install third-party drivers? Did you read the workarounds in the Bug Report you linked to? Did you try them? Or are you asking us to explain them? The question is unclear.

Comment: yep i have a nvidia card, and i selected install third-party drivers, and i havent tried anything, im new at ubuntu, so im asking for help

Comment: Try installing again without checking the third-party drivers box. They can be installed afterward.